# Visual Studio 2010 designer not displaying AJAX tab container correctly

Tags: asp.net, html, css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-designer

**OverView**

I'm having problem with Ajax Tab Container ,I have added three tabs in it namely "Add User" , "Delete User" and "Update User". I had to add them using "Source View" ,because I was unable to find the smart tag of Ajax Tab Container.

- I can't modify tabs,
- Can't add event handlers,

**Problem**
So the problem is Visual Studio 2010 is not displaying AJAX tab container correctly in the designer and I have to manually modify the control in the "Source View" which is time consuming.
*Inside Visual Studio Ajax Tab Rendering*
[image: Inside Visual Studio Ajax Tab Rendering]

Although the Tab container is correctly rendered in browser.
*Inside FireFox Ajax Tab container Rendering Rendering*
[image: Inside FireFox Rendering]

**How to fix it ?**

**Update:**
[found this post related](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2009/01/05/tabcontainer-rendered-incorrectly-in-design-view.aspx)

Comment: Reading your profile you seem quite a keen .NET developer. It seems unexpected that you'd want to use the designer, and more surprising that you find Source View to be a waste of time.

Comment: @JamieDixon using Source View is good for practising at first ,but I'm short of time on this project gotta complete it fast.

Comment: @dotNetSoldier If you're short of time, stop worrying about how it displays in Visual Studio. This is not a representation of how it will display in any browser.

Comment: Ok curt ,gotta get dirty in the source code ,+1 for ur valuable time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to manually modify the control in the "Source View" which is a
>   waste of time.

This is not a waste of time. Personally I don't think Design Mode should be used at all, and that you should familarise yourself with understanding the code so that you can visualise this yourself.

If you are interested in becoming a professional web developer, then I would recommend removing Design Mode from Visual Studio (This is possible through the Tools option*). This will then resolve your issue.

*Go to `Tools` > `HTML Designer` > Untick `Enable HTML Designer`

Comment: I have removed "waste of time" from my post :) , +1 for the help

Answer (score 2):

The VS designer can't render everything that a browser can. It's not designed to (sorry, bad pun). It's meant as a design time reference, but you can't see what will truly be rendered until you run your page in various browsers.

Most professional web developers don't use the designer anyway since you can produce cleaner code by hand.

Comment: Ok got your point ,I gotta remove "waste of time" from my post :)